# Change MainActivity background image while in another background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, background

I'm creating a simple little game in Android Studio and I need this feature.

I have the MainActivity and the "Store" Activity.
In the store, I want to buy new backgrounds to the MainActivity, but I want them to change as I buy it.

I have already defined an id to the MainActivity in order to manipulate the background easily.

Note: The following code works if I manipulate the active Activity. For example, I can change the Store BG normally (because it's the open one), but when I try to change the Main's, it crashes!

Take a look at the Store Code.

```
public class LojaGuina extends Activity {

    public Button changeBgButton;
    public static RelativeLayout manipulaLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loja_guina);

        changeBgButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoBgs);
        manipulaLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.idMain);

        changeBgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                manipulaLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.temajail2);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

`idMain` is the id of the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` for communication between `LojaGuina` activity to `MainActivity`. Right now you are trying to change the background of your `MainActivity` when the `LojaGuina` activity is in foreground.

You can pass the resource id for the background from `LojaGuina` using `setResult()` method to `MainActivity`. And `MainActivity()` will receive it inside `onActivityResultMethod()`.